# How to use "SCNVector4Make()"?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, animation, scenekit

I have a short question. I don't know which values I have to put in this function and I can't find any valuable examples on the internet.

This is my function:

I already set up a node and everything else.

```
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(x,y,z,w);
```

What are the values for `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` when I want to turn my object with an angle of `45 degrees`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first value is for "x"
SCNVector4Make(1,0,0,0)

The second is "Y"
SCNVector4Make(0,1,0,0)

The third is "Z"
SCNVector4Make(0,0,1,0)

The fourth "W" is rotation  in radians. To rotate your object on the "x" axis 45 degs. It will look like so...

SCNVector4Make(1,0,0,M_PI/4)

M_PI is equal to 180 degs.

Answer (score 1):

from the SCNNode reference:

> The four-component rotation vector specifies the direction of the rotation axis in the first three components and the angle of rotation (in radians) in the fourth.

Comment: Thank you! But I alreday read the reference. How do I get the three components of the rotation axis? I don't know how to get these 4 numbers from my information - I want to rotate my object by 45 Degress.

Comment: there are infinitely many ways to rotate an object by 45 degrees. You have to decide along which axis you want to rotate. I can be the X axis (1,0,0), the Y axis (0,1,0), the Z axis (0,0,1) or any other arbitrary axis.

Comment: OK. I think I understood what this functions is doing. Probably it's the wrong function. I have to try a little bit more. It seems there is no easy solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2 you can use the following values for 45 degrees rotation in `SCNVector4Make(x, y, z, w)`:

**X-axis**:

```
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, .pi/4)
```

**Y-axis**:

```
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi/4)
```

**Z-axis**:

```
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1, .pi/4)
```

> Remember, `w` parameter must be in Radians,

so `3.14159 / 4 = 0.78539` radians

(or `180 / 4 = 45` degrees).